# Explaining the uniform convergence in the proof of Egoroff's theorem and a comment after the proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The theorem and its proof are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

My questions are:

1-It is not clear for me how the third line from below and the 2 lines above it proof that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $A$, could anyone explain this for me, please?

2-Secondly, it is not clear for me from the comment after the proof, why Egoroff's theorem also holds if the limit function is finite a.e., could anyone explain this for me, please?

Comment: Regarding your first question, those lines give exactly the definition of uniform convergence. Could you explain what about them makes you not see how they establish uniform convergence? For your second question, aside from removing the set $A$ from $E$, consider also removing the null set on which $\{f_n\}$ does not converge.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist so maybe I am confused about uniform convergence of a sequence of functions, could you state it for me please?

Comment: You can use the definition on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition